# Hot to get object key from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, key

I have this array of objects called name[] (for example), as shown in the console log I have printed below.

With each user who logs in, his name will be added to the option with name: key, and another object with all data is added. (This is just how I've got up to now to work, there may be cleaner ways but for now I'm close to getting what I need so no need rework that imo).

```
0:
id: "users"
name: {Dick: true, Harry: true, Tom: true}
__proto__: Object
1:
id: "users"
name: {Dick: true, Harry: true, Tom: true}
__proto__: Object
2:
id: "users"
name: {Dick: true, Harry: true, Tom: true}
__proto__: Object
```

I am aiming to list the different names in a React component. When I try to map through the array as it is, I get  "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child" - because of course the array/objects within are not in the format I need.

I need to map over an array of the names once to add a list to the browser, but for now the names are in an object which is the second value of an oject within an array...

I guess I need to use just one of the objects in the original array (as they are all the same), ignore the 'id' key, then map through the object that contains the different names.

This is a little complex for me, separating/reaching the targeted object from within the other data is tricky.

If you have any ideas on the how to do it, I am open to to suggestions.

Thank you. Regarding how I am trying to return the data to the browser, please see below my current attempt that gives the error mentioned above.

```
 return <div className='container'>

      {/* title */}
      <div className='titleDiv'>
        <h1>React Message App</h1>
        <p className='usersLoggedIn'>Logged in: </p>
        {
          names.map(item => {
            return (
              <p className='usersLoggedIn'>
                {(item.name === this.state.name ? ' ' : item.name)}
              </p>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
```

Comment: Well, no, because I'm not looking to fix that error, per se. I am looking to find out how to extract certain data from within an array of objects.

Comment: I've added the render() code for info

Comment: `item.name` is an `object`, therefore you can not render `object` as the error states. what is the type of `state.name`?

Comment: This is why I wanted to pull the data out of the array/object/object.

Comment: I have now used ```names[0].name``` to pull out the data I need. So now I have an array, each index is the name I need and the value is 'true' (as this is if someone is logged in or not).

Comment: Whenever you have a string as an “index”, it’s actually the key of a property on an object. That object might be an `Array`, but those entries are properties of the object, not entries in the array.

Comment: Which would explain why I am now getting the error .map is not a function when appending it to my 'array' name !  :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
          names.map(item => {
            return (
              <p className='usersLoggedIn'>
                {(item.name === this.state.name ? ' ' : item.name)}
              </p>
            )
          })
```

You're returning `item.name` nested inside your p tag, which is an object. I'm editing my answer to achieve what you explained you wanted :

```js
          names.map((item,i) => {
            return (
              <p className='usersLoggedIn'>
                {(item.name === this.state.name ? ' ' : Object.keys(item.name)[i])}
              </p>
            )
          })
```

This assumes your array, and your object have the same number of elements, which is what I understood from your object structure. I still have to warn you that this is extremely convoluted, and you might want to look into re-structuring your object instead, or at least your map function :

```js
          Object.keys(names[0].name).map(item => {
            return (
              <p className='usersLoggedIn'>
                {item}
              </p>
            )
          })
```

Comment: Thanks, Zee. The question was really about pulling out the relevant data from within an object that was in an object within an array. I now have this data in an array, the names being the index and a value that is less relevant. I'll need some type of map funtion from here on. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Perfect. As I'd already pulled the object data from the complex array earlier, I've used your code as the following  ``` Object.keys(names).map ```  . Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In the render method when you are iterating through the names array, `item.name` consists of the inner object like `{Dick: true, Harry: true, Tom: true}` which is rendered inside a `<p>` tag. This is invalid because an object cannot be a children node of the p tag let alone any dom element.

If you want to render all of the inner name for each object in the name array , you will have to get the necessary data from the inner object `{Dick: true, Harry: true, Tom: true}` and then render it.

**example**

```
 return <div className='container'>

  {/* title */}
  <div className='titleDiv'>
    <h1>React Message App</h1>
    <p className='usersLoggedIn'>Logged in: </p>
    {
      names.map(item => {
        return (
          <p className='usersLoggedIn'>
            { // parse the inner object to get all the name keys
               Object.keys(item.name).map((innerItem) => <span>{innerItem}&nbsp;</span>)
            }
          </p>
        )
      })
    }
  </div>
```

Comment: This is close to what I need. I've managed now using ```names[0].name``` to get an array with the index as the individual name and the value as 'true'. So I'll need something similiar to what you have there but for an array and not an object.

Comment: `names[0].name` will give you the inner object `{Dick: true, Harry: true, Tom: true}` and not an array. `Obect.keys(item.name)` will give an array of the keys of innerItem like `['Dick', 'Harry', 'Tom']` whick then we can iterate easily with map.
If you also want the value of each name key value `true`, you can get it by accessing `item[innerItem]` inside the map callback.

Comment: True. Just realised as .map function not working...  Thank you.

Comment: The example i showed in my answer is a simple way to do it, which is rendering the name keys. You can now use any jsx to render the names as needed. There can be optimizations though. Please mention specifically if you confused with any kind of change in the code.
Also, please mark the answer as accepted if suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you need?

[image: Edit quirky-gagarin-uq1n3]

What it does:

- Filters all the names (keys in `name` property of each object in the array)
- Display names that is not equal to the `state.name`

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "users",
    name: { Dick: true, Harry: true, Tom: true }
  },
  {
    id: "users",
    name: { Dick: true, Harry: true, Tom: true }
  },
  {
    id: "users",
    name: { Dick: true, Harry: true, Tom: true }
  }
];

const getAllUsers = () => {
  return data.reduce((arr, obj) => {
    const names = Object.keys(obj.name);
    const newNames = names.filter(name => {
      return !arr.includes(name);
    });
    return arr.concat(newNames);
  }, []);
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: "Harry"
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        {getAllUsers().map(user => (
          <p>{user === this.state.name ? "" : user}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mehmet, I just got the working response from Zee above. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you would like to filter out the values and/or compare with the state, it's better to abstract that function outside of the render for cleaner code.